# rEFInd takes 10 seconds to load

Tags: windows-8, arch-linux, uefi, refit

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430 (Core i5, Ivy Bridge).  I converted my system from BIOS-MBR to UEFI-GPT.  This worked perfectly.  I have [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) configured to load both Arch Linux and Windows 8.1.  This also works perfectly.

The problem is how long it takes for rEFInd to appear.  It takes almost 10 seconds for it to appear.  Why does it take so long to appear?

Here's my `refind.conf` file: http://pastebin.com/8FVJ36wE

I thought changing my display resolution would help, but it didn't.  I also tried to disable auto-detection and it still takes 10 seconds to load.  What could be causing it to boot so slowly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes unnecessary EFI drivers can cause rEFInd to start up more slowly, so check for that. (Drivers are normally installed in the `drivers` or `drivers_x64` directory of the rEFInd installation directory -- so usually `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers` or `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers_x64` in Linux.) Normally, you need just one driver, for the filesystem type on which your kernel resides.

Comment: That's a good thought.  I'll try that out.  I guess I just need ext2 (for `/boot`).

Comment: Oddly, this didn't seem to make any difference.  It still takes 10 seconds to appear.

Comment: Check your firmware settings for any options related to "CSM" or "legacy" support. If active, try deactivating them, since they typically add a few seconds to the boot time. (I'd expect this to affect the time to boot *anything,* but if you happened to activate BIOS/CSM/legacy support at the same time you installed rEFInd, you might mistakenly think that rEFInd was taking its time coming up.)

Comment: It's set to UEFI only and CSM is disabled.  I'll check some other BIOS settings.  Maybe it's trying to boot from other devices before the HDD.

Comment: Use `efibootmgr -v` in Linux to check the firmware's boot priorities (see the `BootOrder` line). It could be that something is set to launch before rEFInd but that it's exiting without doing anything or is failing. You might also try replacing the ext2fs EFI driver with the ext4fs one; there's a slim chance that the ext2fs driver is being sluggish for some reason but that the ext4fs driver would be more efficient.

Comment: rEFInd seems to be 1st in the BootOrder line.  I tried removing all but the ext2 driver and it didn't work, so I'll try removing all but the ext4 one maybe?  I'm not sure if that'll do anything.  I think I'm ok with just dealing with it for now.

Comment: Since you're using Arch, another possibility is to use FAT on your `/boot` partition and do away with the EFI drivers entirely. (Some distributions rely on symbolic links in `/boot`, but Arch doesn't. In fact, many Arch users mount the ESP at `/boot`.)

Comment: Right now, `/boot` is ext2 and the ESP is at `/boot/efi`.  That's not a bad suggestion.